# SQL prints out row twice?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have a database table set up storing flight information on a city with the colums Destination_ID, Destinatination_City, Airline, Leaving_From and Arriving.

I run the following query:

```
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $dbQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS 
                WHERE destination_City = '$name' ");

                $dbQuery->execute();
                $airlines= array();
                while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $Airlines[] = $dbRow['Airline']; }


 foreach( $Airlines as $Airline )
 {
 $dbQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS 
 WHERE Airline = '$Airline' AND Destination_City = '$name' ");
 $dbQuery->execute();

 while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 $Arriving = $dbRow ['Arriving'];
 $Leaving_From = $dbRow ['Leaving_From']    ; }

 echo "$Leaving_From to $Arriving" ;
 }
```

This returns two results with the same values except for the arriving column which is different. However when printing it prints the second row out twice instead of printing both rows.

Im not sure why it does this. Could anyone help?

Comment: You need to put the `echo` inside the `while`. As it is currently written, the variables get overriden by the last retrieved row

Comment: @kingkero Just tried this and it now prints row 1 out twice and row 2 out twice?

Comment: Do you have any other code which includes/calls the posted lines?

Comment: I have the above code inside a for each loop which i should have mentioned. Will edit to add it in.

Comment: Putting the echo back into the while loop should work, have you checked the array to see if the airline is being passed twice or there is duplicate in the database?

Comment: @Izion i tried putting the echo inside the while loop but it now prints out as "Leaving_from1 to Arriving_1. Leaving_from1 to Arriving_2" and then repeats this on the next line.

Comment: Little confusing maybe I missed something will take another look, can you  vardump the Airlines array and the DB result and add to your post?

Comment: @OUDK, Just tested this on local server and results come back as they should you must have something wrong elsewhere we cannot see.

Comment: The problem is when both rows have the same airline. I assume it's something to do with the for loop?

Comment: @OUDK It shouldn't do really, the for loop will only go over the airline once (as long as its only in the array once). I will post my example below it may shed some light if you compare the two

Comment: @Izion Thanks. I have edited to add all the code i am using for this.

Comment: @OUDK check out the answer below, I believe your right the loop contained a duplicate but have included two options to fix it

Comment: **WARNING**: `$_GET` data **never** goes directly in the query. If you're using PDO, look at using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). What you have here is extremely dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference for @OUDK:

```
$Airlines = array('Flyr');
$Airlines = array_unique($Airlines);
$name = 'London';



foreach( $Airlines as $Airline )
 {

     $dbQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM DESTINATIONS 
 WHERE Airline = '$Airline' AND Destination_City = '$name' ");

 $dbQuery->execute();

 while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $Arriving = $dbRow ['Arriving'];
     $Leaving_From = $dbRow ['Leaving_From']; 

     echo "$Leaving_From to $Arriving" . '<br>';
 }


 }
```

DB I only have 3 examples:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
| Airline | Destination_City | Leaving_From | Arriving |
+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
| Flyr    | London           | Paris        | London   |
| Flyr    | London           | Rome         | London   |
| Flyr    | London           | Madrid       | London   |
+---------+------------------+--------------+----------+
```

I have London under destination and arriving, was a little confused on that part.

Outputs:

```
Paris to London
Rome to London
Madrid to London
```

EDIT ----------------

I think I see the issue with the last edit you made the code your using to get an array of the airline means that if the airline is in the result more than once it will also be in the array, you can either add the array_unique as above but a better method would be the following:

```
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Airline FROM DESTINATIONS 
                WHERE destination_City = '$name' ");

                $dbQuery->execute();
                $airlines= array();
                while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $Airlines[] = $dbRow['Airline']; }
```

Answer (score 0):

dbQuery fetches one result set with each iteration , so you need to put your echo code inside while loop for printing the result with every iteration. Modify your code accordingly for desired result.